# Django Check if Username already exists

Tags: python, django

Here's my forms.py,

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [  'username', 'first_name', 'password1', 'password2']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

In views.py,

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect(reverse('accounts:profile'))
else:
    form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Right now if i'm using the same username it's raising an error which says "The view accounts.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." How can I fix this issue?

Thank You :)

Comment: The form already does this for you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sir, How can I fix this error "The view accounts.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Comment: Unindent the last line one level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Django form by default does this for you.**

You don't need specific for this.
Beacuse, default `User` Model provided by django doesn't take duplicate username.

**May be some indentation problem**

```
def register(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
          form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
              form.save()
              . . . . 
     else:
         form = RegistrationForm()
     return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', {'form': form})
     #^^^^^Indentation here take return statement outside else
```

Comment: Sir, How can I fix this error "The view accounts.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Comment: post your complete `views.py`.

Comment: Sir, just posted in Question

Comment: @ShivamKumarDodval, I have updated the answer have a look.

Comment: Thank You Sir, Working perfectly fine!

Comment: @ShivamKumarDodval, feel privileged to help you.